# Nivo Slider To Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, nivo-slider

Ive recently downloaded the NIVO Slider package to my desktop as i wish to integrate this into my WP theme.

Ive zipped the JS files etc to my directory, however do i have to call it via functions. Is there a quick tutorial or can someone point me in the direction of how to perform this please.

Do i have to put a function call in the functions.php file, then add the  wrapper etc to the body of the section i wish to view this as well as the images in a folder?

Ive got one scroller atm, however i feel its not suitable for what i require and want to avoid using the plugin if possible.

thanks
Kirsty

CODE:

***Placed in Header.php***

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<!-- Include the Nivo Slider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/scripts/nivoslider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- Include the Nivo Slider JS file -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/scripts/nivoslider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Set up the Nivo Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

Placed in the page.php above content:

```
<div id="sliderwrap">
<div id="slider">
<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>nemo.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>toystory.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an      example of a caption" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>walle.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the jQuery hard coded version?  Why not just get the Nivo for WordPress version, its $19 for one site.  There's also a full tutorial on the Nivo site for the jQuery version.  See it here: [Nivo Slider Tutorial](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/)

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the comments, yep im attempting the hard coded version. Ive got it, and it appears to be working, however for some reason its not finding my images... any ideas? I have written the code above i have inputted...

Comment: Hey, no problem.  Add a / between `<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>` and the rest of your image path.  Also, if the images are in a directory you'll need to have that as part of your image path.

Example:
`<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />`

Comment: What is the URL to the site in question?

Comment: well ive got this in the main theme directory. Its on a local host... so do i put the whole c: stuff???

Comment: its currently just on my local atm

Comment: tbf i aint even found the blooming CSS for the wrapper yet! goodness knows where that is :S

Comment: We can't see it if its on a local host.  Just make sure all your paths are correct, the paths to jquery, the nivo script, the nivo css, and the images that are to be in the slider.

Comment: Have i included everything in the code above? Have i missed anything out??? If not i will check the paths. Because it appears to be scrolling, however its just pulling blank image

Comment: If its scrolling, but there are no images then I would assume its an incorrect image path issue.  Where are your images?  From what you posted above it looks correct aside from the missing / that I commented on earlier, but its hard to diagnose without seeing it in action.

Comment: You could try to create a new folder in the theme's directory called nevopics and then try this for the path: `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nevopics/imgname.jpg" />`

Don't forget to put the pics for the slider in the new nevopics folder.

Comment: Hi andy, sorted it :)... turns out it was just me being a pleb!